# Small size words while contraction of the table to be fitted to the page

Tags: tables

Regarding this code my table is fit to the page but the size of words are diminished. What should I do?

```
\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \caption{Printing parameters}
    \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
        & Layer height, mm & First layer speed, mm/s   &Printing speed, mm/s  & Extruder temperature, °C & Bed temperature, °C & Extrusion multiplier & Extrusion width, mm & Fan speed, \% \\ \hline
        Carbon fiber tow&  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
    \end{tabular}
}
    \label{table3}
\end{table}
```

Thanks

Comment: never use resizebox on tables

Comment: You never should use `\resizebox`  with tables – it leads to inconsistent font sizes. You have several possibilities: using fixed width column types, changing the font size at the very beginning of the `table` environment and reducing the value of `tabcolsep` (6pt by default).

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options?

Comment: Thank you..................